# Show Record which not exist in MYSQL, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

need help....

i've had table like this

```
date_id hour_id value_1
2012-11-03  1   90.7942
2012-11-03  2   113.441
2012-11-03  3   107.419
2012-11-03  4   89.418
2012-11-03  5   86
2012-11-03  6   103.283
2012-11-03  7   96.5645
2012-11-03  8   98.0877
2012-11-03  9   95.0196
2012-11-03  10  95.7386
2012-11-03  11  94.0219
2012-11-03  12  99.8164
2012-11-03  13  96.867
2012-11-03  14  93.5112
2012-11-03  15  99.4857
2012-11-03  16  92.5523
2012-11-03  17  97.2775
2012-11-03  18  91.7806
2012-11-03  19  93.3862
2012-11-03  20  89.3597
2012-11-03  21  96.96
2012-11-03  22  98.0562
2012-11-03  23  96.6908
```

which date_id & hour_id as CATEGORY for highcharts

which 12:00 AM its not exist..

```
what i want to do is still show the date 

|date_id    | hour_id | value_1 |
|2012-11-03 |    0    |         |
|2012-11-03 |    1    | 90.7942 |
|2012-11-03 |    2    | 113.441 |
|2012-11-03 |    3    | 107.419 |
|
|
|
.....
```

i want to validate it with PHP and highcharts...
kindly need your help
sorry for my bad english

update:

query that i use for this :

> $d1 = '2012-11-02'; $d2 = '2012-11-03';
>
> $sql   = "SELECT distinct MSC 
>                         FROM `scrkpi_h` 
>                         WHERE MSC like 'MSPLG%'
>                         AND descr = 32";
>                 $query_n = mysql_query($sql);
>                 while($ret_n = mysql_fetch_array($query_n ))
>                 {
>                     $nodes = $ret_n[0];
>                     $nodes_l[]=$ret_n[0];
>                 }
>
> while(strtotime($d1) <= strtotime($d2))
>   {
>
> for($h=0;$h<24;$h++)
>   {
>                         $query = mysql_query($sql);
>                         while($ret = mysql_fetch_array($query ))
>                         {
>
> ```
>                       $q1 = mysql_query("SELECT value 
>                                   FROM scrkpi_h 
>                                   WHERE date_id = '$d1' 
>                                   AND hour_id = '$h' 
>                                   AND msc = '$ret[0]'
>                                   AND descr='32'");
>                       while($scr=mysql_fetch_array($q1))
>                       {   
>                               echo "$ret[0] $d1 $h $scr[0]";
>                               echo "<br>";
>
>                       }   
>                   }
>               }
>               $d1 = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($d1)));
>
>           }
> ```

i'm using this loop **for($h=0;$h<24;$h++)** to validate with table.
but if the table doesnt have *hour_id* which i loop it return empty.

Comment: You want an empty column at 2012-11-03 shown on the chart?

Comment: empty value exactly...
i need it in the chart, cause if '2012-11-03 0' doesnt exist, the data will shifting to the left...
its happend when i used multiple series lines chart

Comment: How your output from php looks like ?

Answer (score 0):

With what i undestood, which is not much this should do the trick:

```
SELECT table.* FROM table ...
UNION
SELECT '2012-11-03', '', ''
```

If you need a better answer explain more - What is the exact query you are using, do you expect sometimes to have a value for "12:00" and etc ...

Comment: i already update my query dude...
i expect every missing record or uncomplete record in my tabel(not just 12:00 AM), PHP still able to show the missing record to fill the empty value in the highcharts

Answer (score 0):

You are maybe looking for this:

[documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.showEmpty)

with this setting:

```
|2012-11-03 |    0    |    0    |
```

Comment: yes, more like that...
the data represent the category, which 1st array category = 1st array data..
but if some value was removed (data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],)
the graph will not valid anymore

Comment: than instead of remove try set it to 0! (and redraw)

Comment: if i set it to 0 the graph on that hour will be drop to zero..
what i want its like an empty line ---------  -----------

Comment: have you tired set it to `false` or `null`?

Comment: @alexalexalex or maybe you should use column chart instead of line

Comment: got request to use line chart dude.... :)
null i already try, but false not yet... i will try it..